# Error Notice: Undefined index appear

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three checkboxes ,the user should check one or 2 choices.

when I checked 2 choices an error message appear.

```
    $workshop1Day1 = $_POST["workshop1Day1"];
    $workshop2Day1 = $_POST["workshop2Day1"];
    $workshop3Day1 = $_POST["workshop3Day1"];


 $requete = "INSERT INTO Participant ( NameSurname,workshop1Day1,workshop2Day1,workshop3Day1)
                      VALUES ('$NameSurname', '$workshop1Day1', '$workshop2Day1', '$workshop3Day1')";
        $result = @mysql_query($requete);
```

**error:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: workshop3Day1
```

Then I have tried the following code (eg :in case the checkbox number 3 not checked),the same error appear

```
  $workshop1Day1=' ';
  $workshop2Day1='';
  $workshop3Day1='';

  $workshop1Day1 = $_POST["workshop1Day1"];
  $workshop2Day1 = $_POST["workshop2Day1"];
  $workshop3Day1 = $_POST["workshop3Day1"];

if (isset($workshop1Day1)&& isset($workshop2Day1)&& !isset($workshop3Day1))
{

    $requete = "INSERT INTO Participant ( NameSurname,workshop1Day1,workshop2Day1,workshop3Day1)
                  VALUES ('$NameSurname', '$workshop1Day1', '$workshop2Day1', '$workshop3Day1')";
    $result = @mysql_query($requete);
```

i know that isset is the solution but how?

Comment: You get the error here: `$_POST["workshop3Day1"]`, because *it* is *not set*...! \*hint\*hint\*think\*about\*it!\*

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: `$workshop3Day1` is set, you're are setting it to an empty string when you do this `$workshop3Day1 = $_POST["workshop3Day1"];` you should use empty

Comment: Checkboxes which are NOT checked in an html form are **NOT** submitted with the data, so you're trying to use a $_POST value that doesn't exist, hence your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the warning because you're not running `isset` on the source variable, just on what you assign it to.

This line (`$workshop3Day1 = $_POST["workshop3Day1"];`) will raise the warning because that array index doesn't exist. Instead, use the isset on that line, then use the result of that in your if condition. Something like this:

```
$workshop1Day1 = isset($_POST["workshop1Day1"]) ? $_POST["workshop1Day1"] : 0;
$workshop2Day1 = isset($_POST["workshop2Day1"]) ? $_POST["workshop2Day1"] : 0;
$workshop3Day1 = isset($_POST["workshop3Day1"]) ? $_POST["workshop3Day1"] : 0;
```

Then remove the `isset` from your `if` condition.